# Use exported WMS layer style (.qml or .sld) to style a vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, style, qml

I'm reaching out for assistance with a problem I've encountered while working with QGIS. My goal is to apply the styling defined in a WMS (Web Map Service) layer's exported style file (either .sld for Styled Layer Descriptors or .qml for QGIS Style Files) directly to a local vector layer within QGIS.

are there any possibilities?